# Reversing the sequence of a string

Tags: c++

A fairly simple program, trying to reverse the characters in a null terminated string in C++, but something seems to be going wrong.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void reverse(char*);

int main(){

    char *str;
    cout<< "Please enter a string, no spaces please..";
    cin >> str;


    //reverse(str);

}

void reverse(char *str){

    char temp;
    size_t len = strlen(str); 

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len/2; i--)
    {
        temp = str[i];
        str[i] = str[len-i-1];
        str[len-i-1] = temp;

    }

}
```

Getting the following error

```
Bus error: 10
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: "Something" is going wrong. You really ought to explain that "something" more. That might involve learning how to use your platform's debugger.

Answer (score 2):

- Allocate memory for `str` before use `char *str = new char[25];`
- In `reverse` function for `for` loop increment `i` `for (size_t i = 0; i < len/2; i++ )`
- Deallocate memory after use `delete [] str ;`

Comment: A string can be reversed in-place without allocating new memory.  Hint: `std::swap`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this modified version of your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

void reverse(char*);

int main(){

    char str[1024]; // buffer of 1024 chars
    cout<< "Please enter a string, no spaces please..";
    cin >> str;


    reverse(str);
    cout << "\nReversed: " << str;

}

void reverse(char *str){

    char temp;
    size_t len = strlen(str); 

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len/2; i++) // loop until half of the user input
    {
        temp = str[i];
        str[i] = str[len-i-1];
        str[len-i-1] = temp;

    }
}
```

I simply added the array of char `char str[1024];` to store the user input.. and changed the loop to: `for (size_t i = 0; i < len/2; i++)`

However, you **must** be very careful with the above code.. it works properly if the size of the input is less than the array fixed size.

Answer (score 0):

You are decrementing iterator `i` insted of incrementing it. A little bit compact version of yours:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>

void reverse(char* const str)
{
    unsigned long const len = strlen(str);
    for(unsigned long i = 0; i < len >> 1; i++)
        std::swap(str[len - i - 1], str[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main() {

  // You can't read something to nowhere.
  // String will be holded in static array.
  char str[1024];

  // To keep it as null terminated string after
  // writing of inputed string: `std::cin` don't
  // write null character after writing of data.
  memset(str, 0, 1024);

  std::cin >> str;

  // If you do reversing of strings in C++,
  // you shouldn't use hand written loops: 
  std::reverse(str, str + strlen(str));

  std::cout << str << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: I think his interest lies exactly in implementation...